# How to return the absolute path of recursively matched arguments? (BASH)

Tags: bash, recursion, grep, command-line-interface

OK, so simple enough.. I want to recursively search a directory for files with a specific extension - and then perform an action on those files.

`# pwd`<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
`/dir`

`# ls -R | grep .txt | xargs -I {} open {}` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
`The file /dir/reallyinsubfolder.txt does not exist.`  ⬅ fails (bad)
Not output, but succeeds.. `/dir/fileinthisfolder.txt`  ⬅ opens silently (good)

This *does find* ALL the files I am interested in… but *only OPEN's* those which happen to be "1-level" deep.  In this case, the attempt to open `/dir/reallyinsubfolder.txt` fails, as `reallyinsubfolder.txt` is actually `/dir/sub/reallyinsubfolder.txt`.

I understand that grep is simply returning the matched filename… which then chokes (in this case), the open command, as it fails to reach down to the correct sub-directory to execute the file..

**How do I get `grep` to return the full path of a match?**

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `find` command -

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -iname "*.txt" -exec action to perform {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name *.txt -exec open {};
```

(Decorate with backslashes of your needing)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're asking the wrong question; [parsing `ls(1)` output in this fashion is far more trouble than it is worth](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

What would work far more reliably:

```
find /dir -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 open
```

or

```
find /dir -name '*.txt' -exec open {} \;
```

`find(1)` does not mangle names nearly as much as `ls(1)` and makes executing programs on matched files far more reliable.